# Windows 10 remote wakes automatically after sleep

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, sleep

I connect to a Windows 10 Pro machine via remote desktop connection from another Windows 10 environment. When I try to put the remoted machine to sleep manually (via the start menu power button) the following happens:

1. The remoted machine powers off as expected
2. The Remote Desktop Connection session gets terminated (but before that it shows the lock screen for a few seconds)
3. A few seconds later the remoted machine comes off the sleep state and comes back online

How can I remotely put a machine to sleep?

Comment: Are the two machines on the same LAN and do you have "Wake on LAN" turned on the destination machine? It is possible that MSTSC figures out the connection went down, tries to reconnect to the machine, Wake on LAN kicks in and wakes up the box.

Comment: Yes, this is my setup and it can be that this is the reason.